# Is there any wrong in my focal loss derivation?

Tags: deep-learning, math, objective-functions, calculus

Assume $\mathbf{X} \in R^{N, C}$ is the input of the softmax $\mathbf{P} \in R^{N, C}$, where $N$ is number of examples and $C$ is number of classes:

$$\mathbf{p}_i = \left[ \frac{e^{x_{ik}}}{\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_{ij}}}\right]_{k=1,2,...C} \in R^{C} \mbox{ is a row vector of } \mathbf{P}$$

Consider example $i$-th, because softmax function $\mathbf{p}:R^C \mapsto R^C$ (eliminate subscript $i$ for ease notation), so the derivative of vector-vector mapping is Jacobian matrix $\mathbf{J}$:

$$\mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{x}) = \left[ \frac{\partial \mathbf{p}}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial \mathbf{p}}{\partial x_2}, ..., \frac{\partial \mathbf{p}}{\partial x_C}  \right] = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \frac{\partial p_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial p_1}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial p_1}{\partial x_C} \\ 
    \frac{\partial p_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial p_2}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial p_2}{\partial x_C} \\
    \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\ 
    \frac{\partial p_C}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial p_C}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial p_C}{\partial x_C} 
\end{bmatrix}
\in R^{C, C}
$$

$\mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{x})$ is called the derivative of vector ${\mathbf{p}}$ with respect to vector $\mathbf{x}$

$$\mbox{1) Derivative in diagonal:}\frac{\partial p_{k}}{\partial x_{k}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{k}}\left( \frac{e^{x_k}}{\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}} \right)$$

$$ = \frac{\left( \frac{\partial e^{x_k}}{\partial x_k} \right)\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j} - e^{x_k}\left(\frac{\partial \sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}}{\partial x_k} \right)}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}\right)^2} \mbox{  (Quotient rule) }$$

$$ = \frac{e^{x_k}\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j} - e^{x_k} e^{x_k}}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}\right)^2} = \frac{e^{x_k}(\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j} - e^{x_k})}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}\right)^2}$$

$$ = \frac{e^{x_k}}{\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}} \left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j} - e^{x_k}}{\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}}\right) = \frac{e^{x_k}}{\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}} \left(1 - \frac{e^{x_k}}{\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}}\right)$$

$$\rightarrow \frac{\partial p_{k}}{\partial x_{k}} = p_{k}(1-p_{k})$$

$$\mbox{2) Derivative not in diagonal } k \neq c \mbox{ :} \frac{\partial p_{k}}{\partial x_{c}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{c}}\left( \frac{e^{x_k}}{\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}} \right)$$

$$ = \frac{\left( \frac{\partial e^{x_k}}{\partial x_c} \right)\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j} - e^{x_k}\left(\frac{\partial \sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}}{\partial x_c} \right)}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}\right)^2} \mbox{  (Quotient rule) }$$

$$ = \frac{0 - e^{x_k} e^{x_c}}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}\right)^2} = -\frac{e^{x_k}}{\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}}\frac{e^{x_c}}{\sum_{j=1}^C e^{x_j}}$$

$$\rightarrow \frac{\partial p_{k}}{\partial x_{c}} = -p_{k}p_{c}$$

$$\rightarrow \mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{x}) =
\begin{bmatrix} 
    p_1(1-p_1) & -p_1p_2 & \dots & -p_1p_C \\ 
    -p_2p_1 & p_2(1-p_2) & \dots & -p_2p_C \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
    -p_Cp_1 & -p_Cp_2 & \dots & p_C(1-p_C)
\end{bmatrix}$$

- Focal Loss: $\displaystyle FL = -\sum_{k=1}^C y_{k} \alpha_{k}(1-p_k)^\gamma \log (p_k)$

$$\nabla_{\mathbf{x}} FL = \nabla_{\mathbf{p}}FL (\mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{x}))^T $$

$$\nabla_{\mathbf{p}} FL = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_1}\\ 
    \frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_2}\\
    \vdots \\
    \frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_C} 
\end{bmatrix} \mbox{ where } \frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_k}
= - y_k\alpha_k \left(-\gamma(1-p_k)^{\gamma-1} \log(p_k) + \frac{(1-p_k)^\gamma}{p_k}  \right) = y_k \alpha_k\gamma(1-p_k)^{\gamma-1}\log(p_k) - y_k\alpha_k\frac{(1-p_k)^\gamma}{p_k}$$

$$\nabla_{\mathbf{x}} FL = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_1}\\ 
    \frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_2}\\
    \vdots \\
    \frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_C} 
\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \frac{\partial p_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial p_1}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial p_1}{\partial x_C} \\ 
    \frac{\partial p_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial p_2}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial p_2}{\partial x_C} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
    \frac{\partial p_C}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial p_C}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial p_C}{\partial x_C} 
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    \sum_{k=1}^C \left(\frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_k}\frac{\partial p_k}{\partial x_1}\right)\\ 
    \sum_{k=1}^C \left(\frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_k}\frac{\partial p_k}{\partial x_2}\right)\\
    \vdots \\
    \sum_{k=1}^C \left(\frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_k}\frac{\partial p_k}{\partial x_C}\right)
\end{bmatrix}^T \in R^C
$$

$$\mbox{Case 1: }\displaystyle \frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_k}\frac{\partial p_k}{\partial x_k} \forall k=1,2,...,C$$

$$\frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_k} \frac{\partial p_k}{\partial x_k} = y_k \alpha_k\gamma(1-p_k)^{\gamma-1}\log(p_k)p_k(1-p_k) - y_k\alpha_k\frac{(1-p_k)^\gamma}{p_k}p_k(1-p_k)$$

$$ = y_k \alpha_k (1-p_k)^{\gamma}(\gamma p_k \log(p_k) - 1 + p_k) $$

$$\mbox{Case 2: } (k \neq c)\displaystyle \frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_k}\frac{\partial p_k}{\partial x_c}$$

$$\frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_k} \frac{\partial p_k}{\partial x_c} = - y_k\alpha_k\gamma(1-p_k)^{\gamma-1}\log(p_k)p_kp_c + y_k\alpha_k\frac{(1-p_k)^\gamma}{p_k}p_kp_c$$

$$ = - y_k\alpha_k (1-p_k)^{\gamma-1}p_c(\gamma p_k \log(p_k) - 1 + p_k) $$

$$\mbox{For each } d=1,2,...,C \mbox{ : }\sum_{k=1}^C \left(\frac{\partial FL}{\partial p_k} \frac{\partial p_k}{\partial x_d}\right) = y_d \alpha_d (1-p_d)^{\gamma}(\gamma p_d \log(p_d) - 1 + p_d) + \sum_{c \neq d}^C \left( - y_d\alpha_d (1-p_d)^{\gamma-1}p_c(\gamma p_d \log(p_d) - 1 + p_d) \right) = y_d\alpha_d(1-p_d)^{\gamma-1}(\gamma p_d \log(p_d) - 1 + p_d)\left(1-p_d -\sum_{c \neq d}^C(p_c)\right) $$

$$\rightarrow \nabla_{\mathbf{x}} FL = \left[ y_d\alpha_d(1-p_d)^{\gamma-1}(\gamma p_d \log(p_d) - 1 + p_d)\left(1-p_d -\sum_{c \neq d}^C(p_c)\right) \right]_{d=1,2,...,C}$$

However, the problem is $\left(1-p_d -\sum_{c \neq d}^C(p_c)\right) = 0$ (because sum of all probabilities is 1) then the whole expression collapses to $0$.

Is there any wrong in my focal loss derivation?

Reference:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02002